# Opencv increases image's size after rotation

Tags: opencv, tiff, image-rotation

I am using opencv in python to rotate an image and the original and the resulted images are differrent is somethings, I am doing my transformation through this part of code:

```
img = cv2.imread("image.tif")    
new_image = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols / 2, rows / 2), correction_angle, 1)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(img, new_image , (cols, rows))
cv2.imwrite("Rotated_image.tif", dst)
```

- The original image's size is 1.7 Mb, The image's resolution is 300
  dpi, and the color space is YCbCr.
- The issue is that the resulting image with 12.5 Mb size, 96 dpi, the color space is RGB, and with compression "LZW"!

My question is that: Can I keep the main properties of the original image? and why rotating an image changes the size this way?

Note: The bit depth is 24 in both images.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `cv2.imread` with only the name of the file uses the default value `cv.IMREAD_COLOR` for the second parameter, about which [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d99277ac48327799c80) says:

> If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.

So, your image is always converted to RGB. You can try using `cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR` for the second parameter of `imread`, but I don't think you can use `cv2.warpAffine` on it trivially then.

The difference in the stored DPI information stems from the fact that you write the new image without any meta data. `imwrite` allows you to specify parameters (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce)), but, unfortunately, they are not very well documented. I am not sure if this kind of data can be written out of the box with OpenCV.